# How to replace same values in different ways in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, ksort

I have a such code for Lithuanian declension:

```
<?php
    $word               = "namas";
    $string             = str_repeat("$word ", 4);
    $patterns           = array();
    $patterns[0]        = '/as/';
    $patterns[1]        = '/as/';
    $patterns[2]        = '/as/';
    $patterns[3]        = '/as/';
    $replacements       = array();
    $replacements[0]    = 'as';
    $replacements[1]    = 'o';
    $replacements[2]    = 'ui';
    $replacements[3]    = 'a';
    ksort($patterns);
    ksort($replacements);
    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

How could I have replacement in different way? I would like to have such result:
**namas namo namui nama**
But everywhere I have "namo namo namo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I think you want:

```
<?php
$word ="namas";
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/as/';
$patterns[1] = '/as/';
$patterns[2] = '/as/';
$patterns[3] = '/as/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'as';
$replacements[1] = 'o';
$replacements[2] = 'ui';
$replacements[3] = 'a';

ksort($patterns);
ksort($replacements);

foreach ($patterns as $idx => $pat)
{
    echo " " . preg_replace ($pat, $replacements[$idx], $word);
}

?>
```

It is further simplified as:

```
<?php
$word ="namas";
$pattern = '/as/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'as';
$replacements[1] = 'o';
$replacements[2] = 'ui';
$replacements[3] = 'a';

foreach ($replacements as $replace)
{
    echo " " . preg_replace ($pattern, $replace, $word);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think like a loop,

1. change **`as`** to **`as`** and string became **'namas namas namas namas'**
2. change **`as`** to **`o`** and string became **'namo namo namo namo'**
3. change **`as`** to **`ui`** and no match (**'namo namo namo namo'** remains)
4. change **`as`** to **`o`** and no match (**'namo namo namo namo'** remains)

Comment: Sorry, there was a little mistake. My point is to create a paradigm of declension with some cases. There must be as genitive as dative and so on. In this way I tried to replace "ending".